# HTML/CSS - Navigation bar stretch/fill background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar, nav

*My problems so far are about stylizing my page.*

I've build an **inline** navigation bar but when **I want to change its background color** It does not affect the height that I would like to be colorized. I would like to know if I can do something about it **but also not** to affect the size or style of my navigation bar

PICTURES ( I use `background-color : green;` for this ):

[image]

```css
body{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  font-family : 'Arial',serif;
}

/*nav class  */
.nav {
  background-color : green;
  color: white;
  list-style : none;
  text-align : right;
  padding : 0px 0 0px 0;
}

/*A li tag in a .nav class*/
.nav > li {
  display : inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;/*same as 0 25px 0 25px ( top left bottom right */
  font-size: 14px;
}

/*a tag inside a li tag inside a .nav class*/
.nav > li > a { 
  text-decoration : none;
  color: black;
}

/* a tag inside a li tag inside a .nav class while mouse hovering */
.nav > li > a:hover {
  color : #c1c1c1;
}

.logo {
  float : left;
  padding-left : 25px;
}

.logo > .logo-image {
  position: relative;
  bottom : 8px;
  width : 128px;
}

.banner {
  width : 100%;
  display : block;
}

.banner  > .banner-image{
  width : 100%;
  display : block ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DeckArts Graphics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo-image" href="#home">
          <img  src="ZE.png" >
        </a>
      </div>

      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="banner">
      <img class="banner-image" src="banner.jpg" >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to set the height of the `.nav` element.

Comment: you've removed the padding, but not the margin. The background applies to the padding, but not to the margin, try resetting the margin to 0 and adding some top/bottom padding

Comment: Set the height style for the nav element.

Comment: @Stu you've been really helpful I changed the `padding : 20px 0 20px 0;`
and added `margin : 0px;` but changing the **height** it just ruins the style of my page . Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting margins and applying padding to the nav does the job.

Specifically,

1. Change `padding : 0px 0 0px 0;` to `padding : 10px 0 10px 0;`
2. Add `margin:0px`.

Demo below.

```css
body{
  margin : 0;
  padding : 0;
  font-family : 'Arial',serif;


}
/*nav class  */
.nav {
  background-color : green;
  color: white;
  list-style : none;
  text-align : right;
  padding : 10px 0 10px 0;
  margin:0px;
}
/*A li tag in a .nav class*/
.nav > li {
  display : inline-block;
  padding-right: 50px;/*same as 0 25px 0 25px ( top left bottom right */
  font-size: 14px;



}
/*a tag inside a li tag inside a .nav class*/
.nav > li > a { 
  text-decoration : none;
  color: black;
}
/* a tag inside a li tag inside a .nav class while mouse hovering */
.nav > li > a:hover {
  color : #c1c1c1;
}
.logo {

  float : left;
  padding-left : 25px;
}
.logo > .logo-image {

  position: relative;
  bottom : 8px;
  width : 128px;
}
.banner {
  width : 100%;
  display : block;
}
.banner  > .banner-image{
  width : 100%;
  display : block ;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>DeckArts Graphics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <ul class="nav">
      <div class="logo">
        <a class="logo-image" href="#home">
          <img  src="ZE.png" >
        </a>
      </div>

      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Projects">Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="banner">
      <img class="banner-image" src="banner.jpg" >
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe your answer is better and clean, will remove mine

Comment: @nicael as @Stu said but in my case I changed it to `padding : 20px 0 20px 0;`